# iterate through Json array without having a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

First of all, this question might have been asked several times already, but every thread I found didn't help me. I would appreciate if one could rewrite my function below.

I have the following array with Json objects.

The goal is to get the "url" values. Right now I get every value from that array.

```js
a = [{
  "result": [{
      "name": [
        "name"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": [
        "name 2"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.org"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": [
        "name 1"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.biz"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": [
        "name 3"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.jp"
      ]
    }
  ]
}];
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "How to explicitly get the url value?'";
loopThrough(a);

function loopThrough(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {
      console.log(obj[key]);
    } else {
      loopThrough(obj[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
</div>
```

How would I access each "url" element in this array?

Maybe there is also a smarter solution than this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
a = [{
  "result": [{
      "name": [
        "name"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": [
        "name 2"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.org"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": [
        "name 1"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.biz"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": [
        "name 3"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.jp"
      ]
    }
  ]
}];
loopThrough(a);

// Uses ES6 syntax
function loopThrough(obj) {
  obj[0].result.forEach(r => console.log(r.url[0]));
}
```

Comment: @AppRoyale if this is a correct answer then tick is as such. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try it yourself.

```js
var a = [{
  "result": [{
      "name": [
        "name"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": [
        "name 2"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.org"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": [
        "name 1"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.biz"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": [
        "name 3"
      ],
      "url": [
        "www.bar.jp"
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

var urls=a[0].result.reduce(function(urls,it){
  return urls.concat(it.url);
},[]);
console.log(urls);
```

Comment: Your answer will iterate 2 times on the array. That's a bit too much for what OP asks

Comment: I don't think that using `reduce` and `map` in this case makes the code clearer. But that's m point of view

Comment: @Weedoze you are right,that I think too more,thanks,I'll change the answer later.